# Series data structure in pandas

Tags: pandas

In the [overview page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/overview.html) of the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) documentation the Series data structure is described as 'homogeneously-typed'.

```
Data Structures
Dimensions  Name    Description
1   Series  1D labeled homogeneously-typed array
2   DataFrame   General 2D labeled, size-mutable tabular structure with potentially heterogeneously-typed column
```

However it is possible to create Series objects with multiple data-types.

```
pd.Series(data=[1,2,3,4,5,'x'], index=['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
#=>a    1
#  b    2
#  c    3
#  d    4
#  e    5
#  f    x
#  dtype: object
```

So what could be the meaning of `homogeneously-typed`mentioned in pandas documentation?

Comment: Pick one of (int, categorical, float, string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple different types in a Series, say `int` and `string`, all of the data will get upcasted to **the same** `dtype=object` (as you can see from your example).

Comment: Is there a way to check the datatypes for all columns of a dataframe and for those columns that have multiple datatypes, list those datatypes out?

Comment: `df.dtypes` gives you the column type. If you want the different types for the elements in a column, you will need to iterate over the rows, e.g. using `type` as in junkaholik's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your series is indeed homogeneously-typed and you can check it's type:

```
s = pd.Series(data=[1,2,3,4,5,'x'], index=['a','b','c','d','e','f'])
s.dtype
> dtype('O')
```

where 'O' is for "object". However, if you check the type of the individual elements of your series, they are different:

```
type(s['a'])
> int
type(s['f'])
> str
```

I think the key thing to remember is that if your Series or DataFrame Column is non homogenously-typed (eventhough technically homogeneously-typed of type "object"), then there are certain pandas functions that won't work.

Here is a better explanation from the pandas documentation's [Essential Basic Functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html):

> If a DataFrame or Panel contains homogeneously-typed data, the ndarray
>   can actually be modified in-place, and the changes will be reflected
>   in the data structure. For heterogeneous data (e.g. some of the
>   DataFrame’s columns are not all the same dtype), this will not be the
>   case. The values attribute itself, unlike the axis labels, cannot be
>   assigned to.
>
> **Note**: When working with heterogeneous data, the dtype of the resulting ndarray will be chosen to accommodate all of the data
>   involved. For example, if strings are involved, the result will be of
>   object dtype. If there are only floats and integers, the resulting
>   array will be of float dtype.